# When invoking methods in Rails apps, what is the convention use parenthesis or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coding-style, methods

What do the vast majority of Rails shops do? Since Ruby allows for either I'm sure there is a set standard I should probably fixate on making a habit since I'm just starting out with Rails.

According to Pragmatic Agile Web Development With Rails (4th Edition):

> In Rails applications, you’ll find that most method calls involved in
>   larger expressions will have parenthe- ses, while those that look more
>   like commands or declarations tend not to have them.

So which is it? Or is it the wild west out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Rails contributing style guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#follow-the-coding-conventions) seems to favor

```
my_method(my_param)
```

over

```
my_method my_param
```

But most of the code I've seen seems to buck that trend.  I would definitely say that you shouldn't use open parentheses for a method call without parameters.  The one guiding principle I've noticed is to emphasize code human readability.  That leads me to the following conclusions:

Don't use the parentheses if
  Your method call has no arguments

```
my_object.my_method
```

Your method call is the only thing on the line

```
my_object.my_method my_params
form.submit "Create"
```

Do use the parentheses if
  Your method call is on the same line as a number of method calls

```
my_object.parse(my_arguments).join(", ").chomp
```

However, there are different conventions for different situations that you'll probably only see by looking at a lot of code.  For example, methods that execute within a class definition mostly don't use parentheses, and have each argument on a different, indented line:

```
validates     :first_name,
              :presence => true,
              :format => { :with => /\S./ }
```